# Graphic memory increasing indefinitely in Android App when navigating between fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, memory, graphics, memory-leaks

I am using android studio and I developed a very simple app. The app has 3 fragments and one `BottomNavigationView` to navigate between the fragments. That is the code I am using to navigate between fragments:

```
private Fragment chartFragment;
private Fragment tutorialFragment;
private Fragment optionFragment;
private FragmentManager fm;
private boolean isDisplaying;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.i("LifeCicle","MainActivity - Created");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    BottomNavigationView navigation = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);

    fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

    if(savedInstanceState != null){
        chartFragment = fm.getFragment(savedInstanceState,CHART_FRAGMENT__KEY);
        tutorialFragment = fm.getFragment(savedInstanceState,TUTORIAL_FRAGMENT__KEY);
        optionFragment = fm.getFragment(savedInstanceState,OPTION_FRAGMENT__KEY);
        isDisplaying = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(IS_DISPLAYING_KEY);
    }else{
        tryCreateFragmentsInstances();
        isDisplaying = false;
    }

    if(!isDisplaying){
        showFragment(chartFragment);
    }
}

private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_home:
                if(tutorialFragment.isHidden()){
                    showFragment(tutorialFragment);
                }
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                if(chartFragment.isHidden()){
                    recreateChartFragment();
                }
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                if(optionFragment.isHidden()){
                    showFragment(optionFragment);
                }
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    Log.i("LifeCicle","MainActivity - Saving States");
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    if(chartFragment.isAdded()){
        fm.putFragment(outState,CHART_FRAGMENT__KEY,chartFragment);
        Log.i("LifeCicle","MainActivity - Chart fragment saved");
    }if(tutorialFragment.isAdded()){
        fm.putFragment(outState,TUTORIAL_FRAGMENT__KEY,tutorialFragment);
        Log.i("LifeCicle","MainActivity - Turotial fragment saved");
    }if(optionFragment.isAdded()){
        fm.putFragment(outState,OPTION_FRAGMENT__KEY,optionFragment);
        Log.i("LifeCicle","MainActivity - Option fragment saved");
    }

    outState.putBoolean(IS_DISPLAYING_KEY,isDisplaying);
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    Log.i("LifeCicle","MainActivity - Restoring States");

}

private void tryCreateFragmentsInstances(){
    if(chartFragment == null){
        chartFragment = ChartFragment.newInstance(gameLetterTime,gameLetterNum);
        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.displayPanel,chartFragment).commit();
    }if(tutorialFragment==null){
        tutorialFragment = TutorialFragment.newInstance();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.displayPanel,tutorialFragment).commit();
    }if(optionFragment==null){
        optionFragment = OptionFragment.newInstance();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.displayPanel,optionFragment).commit();
    }
    hideAllFragments();
}

/**showFragment - Hide all fragments that are being displayed and show that one requested*/
private void showFragment(Fragment fragment){
    hideAllFragments();

    Log.i("LifeCicle","Displaying Fragment: "+fragment);
    fm.beginTransaction()
            .setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in,android.R.anim.fade_out).
            show(fragment).commit();

    isDisplaying=true;
    fm.popBackStack();
}

/**hideAllFragments - hide all fragments that exists in the project
 * @see OptionFragment,ChartFragment,TutorialFragment*/
private  void hideAllFragments(){
    Log.i("LifeCicle","Hiding all fragments");
    if(!chartFragment.isHidden()){
        fm.beginTransaction().hide(chartFragment).commit();
    }if(!optionFragment.isHidden()){
        fm.beginTransaction().hide(optionFragment).commit();
    }if(!tutorialFragment.isHidden()){
        fm.beginTransaction().hide(tutorialFragment).commit();
    }
}

private void recreateChartFragment(){
    fm.beginTransaction().remove(chartFragment).commit();
    chartFragment = ChartFragment.newInstance(gameLetterTime,gameLetterNum);
    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.displayPanel,chartFragment).commit();
    showFragment(chartFragment);
}
```

The fragment `ChartFragment`, for special reasons in my app, I need to recreate it every time I want to display it.

After I finished the app I went to the Profiler of Android studio, running the app with my real device.

The app starts with a memory usage of 30mb while 15mb are described as graphic memory.

My problem is that every time I navigate between the fragments the memory usage increases more and more. I expected the memory usage to grow of course, but until some point.

Navigating back and forth between the 3 fragments I could make the memory usage get up to 80mb with 44mb being described as graphic memory. Below there is a photo of my profiler (All i did during that test was switch between the fragments clicking on the `BottomNavigationView` buttons):

[image: Profiler]

The last garbage collector event I forced to check if it would decrease the memory usage of graphic memory but it didn't work.

Is that normal for such an small app? (inside the fragments are just texts no images at all!) Am i missing some memory leak or doing the navigation between fragments in a really poor way?

I have been trying to reduce that memory usage for days but nothing worked.

Comment: If you're able to get any solution, then please share.

Comment: Unfortunately i couldn't find a solution for that until today. But as it was a very simple app i released it like that. I made a lot of tests after generating the release version and it seemed very stable so it was enough for now, but if i find anything about it in the future i will share it for sure :)

Comment: I believe devices with good memory it works well but with lower-end devices with low RAM it gives OOM pretty soon.

Comment: That might be true, i will try to test it on a lower-end device to check and come back with some results. I forgot to ask you would you do anything different looking to my code ?